# Can't apply no indent on tabular

Tags: indentation, tabularx

I want to align the columns of this tabular but I can't with the following code.

```
\bigskip
\centerline {\large \textbf{Behaviour of A* on a 5x5 grid}}
\bigskip
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar1.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar2.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar3.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar4.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar5-3.png}    \\ \\
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar6.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar7.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar9.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar10.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar11.png}    \\ \\
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar12.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar13.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in]{astar14.png}
\end{tabularx}
```

The output I get is the following with a little bit of horizontal spacing before the first row.

[image]

EDIT!!!:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibtex}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{cleveref} % Used
\usepackage{hvfloat} % Used for an image with caption
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.75,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codepurple},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Remove this line for global equation numbering
\definecolor{antiquefuchsia}{rgb}{0.57, 0.36, 0.51}
\definecolor{azure(colorwheel)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `\centering` in a group.  Also, you shouldn't use `\centerline` which is plain TeX syntax. Use `\multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Behaviour ...}` within `tabularx` instead.

Comment: I am sorry, could you give me a full example using my code pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative without any `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}




\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\large\bfseries Behaviour of $\bm{A^*}$ on a $\bm{5 \times 5}$ grid\par}
  \bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}}  \hfill
\phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}}  \hfill
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

With some vertical distance between the rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}




\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\large\bfseries Behaviour of $\bm{A^*}$ on a $\bm{5 \times 5}$ grid\par}
  \bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  
\medskip

\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  
\medskip

\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}  \hfill
\phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}}  \hfill
\phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.9in]{example-image}}  \hfill
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what if you want to add distance between rows?

Comment: @Ryk: I have updated my answer accordingly. Instead of `\medskip` you could also use `\smallskip` or `\bigskip` depending on the size of the desired vertical space.

Comment: This is a misuse of `\bm`. Use `{\large\bfseries\boldmath Behaviour of $A^*$...\par}` instead.

Comment: Very very bad to see different good answers with 0 scores.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument supply for [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) is short the column specification. Below I correct for that using a `C`entred `X`-column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,bm}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\large\bfseries Behaviour of $\bm{A^*}$ on a $\bm{5 \times 5}$ grid\par}
  \bigskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} C C C C C @{} }
    \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} & 
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} \\ \\
    \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} \\ \\
    \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image} &
      \includegraphics[width=1in]{example-image}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You can see how the grid fits within the page dimensions by adding the `showframe` option to the loading of [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) (loaded just for this example):

[image]

Comment: \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} This line of code doesn't work for me. Look in my post I put the output

Comment: @Ryk: Did you get the output you added in your question using the exact same example from Werner's answer? If not, what did you change? Do you get any error messages? If so which?

Comment: @Ryk: Then you don't have `\usepackage{tabularx}` in your preamble and you're probably defining the `tabularx` environment manually elsewhere.

Comment: I get the output using the same code @leandriis. What do you mean by defining tabularx manually, how is this different from defining it globally.

Comment: this is so strange because if I add tabularx things start crashing.

Comment: @Ryk - A comment such as "things start crashing" is so vague as to be unusable. Do you get any error messages? If so, what exactly do they say?

Comment: @Ryk: Can you also provide the preamble you are using in your document? If "things start crashing" it's because there is already a definition of `tabularx` and loading the package causes conflict. Supplying your preamble should highlight the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Werner done that, thanks! Look on the post

Comment: @Ryk: If I use the preamble from your question in combination with the document body from Werner's answer, I get the following error messages: "! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \bm". and "! LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined.". Adding `\usepackage{bm,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}` as shown in Werner's answer, will fix these errors.

Comment: Apart from that, please mind the correct load order of packages. `hyperref` should (with very few exceptions)  be the last package loaded. `cleveref` is such an exception. So place `\usepackage{hyperref}\usepackage{cleveref}` directly at the end of your preamble.

Comment: @Ryk: I can't compile your document with your preamble and `tabularx` code snippet. You must be doing something else that you're not including.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, with `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}%
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

{\centering \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth} {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc@{}}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries\large\centering Behaviour of A* on a 5x5 grid}\\\\
 \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar1.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar2.png}
 & \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar3.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar4.png}
&\includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar5-3.png} \tabularnewline \\
 \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar6.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar7.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar9.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar10.png} \\ \\
 \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar12.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar13.png}
& \includegraphics[height=1in, width=0.75in]{astar14.png}
\end{tabular*}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can set equal spacing between rows and columns. The placement in the last row can be changed by stating `\centering` or `\raggedright`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{Behaviour of $A^*$ on a $5 \times 5$ grid}

\setlength{\gridsep}{1ex}% or whatever
\setlength{\lineskip}{\gridsep}% space between rows
\setlength{\gridwidth}{0.2\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\gridsep)}% space between cols
\newcommand{\sep}{\hspace{\gridsep}}

\raggedright

\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{Behaviour of $A^*$ on a $5 \times 5$ grid}

\setlength{\gridsep}{2ex}% or whatever
\setlength{\lineskip}{\gridsep}% space between rows
\setlength{\gridwidth}{0.2\dimexpr(\textwidth-4\gridsep)}% space between cols
\newcommand{\sep}{\hspace{\gridsep}}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}\sep
\includegraphics[width=\gridwidth]{example-image}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]